# Installing App using iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch

I've downloaded a game from iTunes to my PC and want to install it in my iPod Touch. I've synced it so many times, but can't install the app. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: What is the game and what is the model of your iPod touch and iOS version (under Settings>General "Version" and "Model" ?

Comment: The Game is Where's my Head. iOS version is 4.3 and model is MC540LL

Comment: Should be compatible. Do other apps sync properly and is there enough free space left on the iPod ? Any kind of error message in iTunes ?

Comment: Nope, no other app is getting synced, I tried installing instagram too. I think I am doing something wrong, but don't know what it is.

Comment: iPad games will not install on iPhones/iPod Touch.  Are you sure you got the right version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check all of the following values (see yellow arrows) in the "apps" tab in iTunes. Does the icon show up in the simulated screen on the right side ?

[image: Apps screen]

Then, right-click on the your iPod in the devices section of the left column in iTunes and choose "reset warnings."

[image: Reset Warnings]

Then sync again (by clicking on the "Apply" button at the bottom right of iTunes) and see if iTunes shows you any error messages.

Answer (score 2):

In iTunes, click on Store, then authorize this computer (i.e., sign in with your username and password). After that, check the application you want to sync to your iPod touch.

Answer (score 0):

On the bar on the left of the iTunes window, click your iPod. Then, go to the "apps" category along the top of the window. Then, make sure one of the following is true:

1. You have "automatically sync new apps" checked on the bottom, or
2. You have the game you want to sync checked.

If this doesn't work, if you have a wi-fi connection (or can get to one), you can go on the app store on your iPod and download it again (if you paid for it on your computer, it will be free on your iPod)

Comment: I've done that already in iTunes and it's not working. I can't access net on my iPod, that's why downloaded on PC.

Comment: "Not working" in what sense?  Which of 1 and 2 did you try?

Comment: Both I've tried. Not working means I can't find the game in the iPod.